# Split all values in columns to create new columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame of integers, which I would like to convert to bits, and then split each resulting bit sequence into separate columns. I figured I could convert my bits to string and then split the strings on whitespace. However, my method does not work.

I create my data frame:

```
r1 <- c(24,25,27)
r2 <- c(98,102,4)
model.data <- as.data.frame(rbind(r1,r2))
```

and then I convert int to bits with:

```
model.data[] <- lapply(model.data, function(x) {
 if(!is.na(x)) as.character(paste(intToBits(x), collapse = " ")) else x
})
```

However, this is where I encounter my first problem. The second row of my data frame now seems to have the same values as the first one:

> model.data$V1
>
> [1] "00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00"
>
> [2] "00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00"

This shouldn't be the case, since the values in the original data frame differ. It's the same case for all the columns here (V2, V3).

My second problem is that I can't split the columns. I try this method:

```
for(i in names(model.data)) {
  a.split <- strsplit(model.data[[i]], split = " ")
  cbind(model.data,a.split)
}
```

but it does nothing.

Could you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: `if` is not vectorised. It only looks at the first element. Use `ifelse()` for a vectorised if. This is what the warning you receive says.

Comment: You need to use `ifesle` which is Vectorized, rather than `if` and then `else`

Comment: Instead of converting to character and strsplit, you could just call rbind on the intToBits results to split them into separate columns, see `rbind(intToBits(2), intToBits(3))`

Comment: Thanks @Adam! I tried `model.data <- rbind(intToBits(r1),intToBits(r2))` and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `apply` over both rows and columns, using `ifelse`. Interestingly, using `lapply` does not seem to work. Here an example for the `apply` solution:

```
r1 <- c(24,25,27)
r2 <- c(98,102,4)
model.data <- as.data.frame(rbind(r1,r2))

model.data[] <- as.data.frame(apply(model.data, c(1,2), function(x) ifelse(!is.na(x), as.character(paste(intToBits(x), collapse = " ")), x)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> model.data
                                                                                                V1
r1 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
r2 00 01 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                                                                                                V2
r1 01 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
r2 00 01 01 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                                                                                                V3
r1 01 01 00 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
r2 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

---

Edit:

To create the new data with one bit per variable, first `lapply` the `strsplit`, giving you a nested list as output, then use a nested `do.call` to first `cbind` the sublists, then `rbind` the result:

```
newCols <- lapply(model.data, function(x) strsplit(x, split = " "))

a.split <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, do.call(cbind, newCols)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> a.split
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24 V25 V26 V27 V28 V29 V30 V31 V32
1 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
2 00 01 00 00 00 01 01 00 00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
3 01 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
4 00 01 01 00 00 01 01 00 00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
5 01 01 00 01 01 00 00 00 00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
6 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
```

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot :)

Comment: Calling `lapply` on a dataframe iterates over the columns and the argument of the function is a list of each column's elements. When passed a list of values, `intToBits` returns a single list of the concatenation of all bit representations, therefore `paste` produces a single string, which is then broadcasted and thus the duplicate values.

Comment: @Pixeluz, see my edit for the second part of your question.

Comment: Thank you @LAP! That answers all my questions :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the function "separate" from tidyr package

```
    library(tidyr)

    # Your data
    r1 <- c(24,25,27)
    r2 <- c(98,102,4)
    # Concatenate r1 and r2
    r3 <- c(r1,r2)
    # Create a dataframe
    model.data <- as.data.frame(r3)
    # Check type of r3
    class(model.data$r3)
    # Transform with "intToBits" function
    model.data[] <- lapply(model.data, function(x) {
     if(!is.na(x)) as.character(paste(intToBits(x), collapse = " ")) else x
    })

    nb = length(unlist(strsplit(model.data$r3[1]," ")))
    # Transform into character
    model.data$r3 <- as.character(model.data$r3)
    # Use "separate" function from tidyr, generating nb variable 
    model.data %>% separate(r3, into = paste0("V",seq(1, nb, by = 1)), sep = " ")
```